# Unable fetch a webpage with curl using php

Tags: php

I'm trying to get access to one api with curl request. As first i copied the page as curl and tested it here:

https://reqbin.com/curl

with this code:

```
curl 'https://api.nfl.com/v1/reroute' \

-H 'x-domain-id: 100' \

-H 'origin: https://www.nfl.com' \

--data-raw 'device_id=0e1940a7-1a21-4dd0-8c9b-048e15b1d6a7&grant_type=client_credentials' \
```

And its working flawlessly. Then i copied the generated php code and i receive this error

```
{
   "errorCode":400,
   "message":"org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 2 errors\nField error in object 'OAuth2Params' on field 'clientId': rejected value []; codes [OAuth2ParamsValid.OAuth2Params.clientId,OAuth2ParamsValid.clientId,OAuth2ParamsValid.java.lang.String,OAuth2ParamsValid]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [OAuth2Params.clientId,clientId]; arguments []; default message [clientId]]; default message [Property: clientId is not valid.]\nError in object 'OAuth2Params': codes [OAuth2ParamsValid.OAuth2Params,OAuth2ParamsValid]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [OAuth2Params.,]; arguments []; default message []]; default message [Invalid oAuth parameters]",
   "timestamp":1601898856620
}
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
 
$url = "https://api.nfl.com/v1/reroute";
 
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);;
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 
$headers = array();
$headers["x-domain-id"] = "100";
$headers["origin"] = "https://www.nfl.com";
$headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
 
$data = "device_id=0e1940a7-1a21-4dd0-8c9b-048e15b1d6a7&grant_type=client_credentials";
 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
 
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
print_r($resp);
 
?>
```

Comment: I think the error is pretty clear : `rejected value`

Comment: You specified the headers in the wrong format. You used a `key=>value` array, but actually, it needs to be of the form `array('Content-type: text/plain', 'Content-length: 100')`

Comment: Property: clientId is not valid. Is it needed there?

Comment: By documentation https://api.nfl.com/docs/global/endpoints/index.html there is not endpoint like /v1/reroute !

Comment: By this description https://api.nfl.com/docs/identity/oauth2/index.html there are some params which are required and you mised them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the header is not passed well. From the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> An array of HTTP header fields to set, in the format
> array('Content-type: text/plain', 'Content-length: 100')

This is how it should look:

```
$headers = array( "x-domain-id: 100", "origin: https://www.nfl.com");
// $headers["x-domain-id"] = "100";
// $headers["origin"] = "https://www.nfl.com";
//$headers["Content-Type"] = "application/form-data";
```

Comment: I am around the corner! me [at] donjajo.com :3 @OrlinHarizanov